# NavigationToolbar2 not working on Mac with wxPython

Tags: macos, user-interface, matplotlib, wxpython, navigationbar

I've been writing a GUI using wxPython 3.0.2 on Python 2.7.8. However, the function on my NavigationToolbar2 is not working correctly on my Mac. I've tried the same code on a PC and it works fine. Is there special thing to be configured?

Comment: What is not working? Is it not showing, are the tools not working ....

Comment: The tools are not working properly. Back and forward never works, zoom just plots some squares on the canvas without really zooming. The original plot is shown correctly.

Comment: Hhm, these things work for me but I am on Win.  You might have better chance of getting an answer on the mpl list matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net , also state the mpl version you are using.